# Azure Logic App - Result Set from Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps, for-json

Creating a logic app to retrieve data from SQL server in JSON format.

Calling SQL Stored Proc from Logic App trigged via HTTP Request.

And using below select Query - FOR JSON to create the output as JSON and using **ResultSet in the response of Logic App.**

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM #TABLENAME FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Data')
```

[image]

But I'm getting the ResultSet along with Table and column name created by SProc select statement.
Which was along with output from Stored Proc and included in the ResultSet of SProc.

[image]

[image: screenshot of output from stored proc]

Does anyone know a method to remove this highlighted output from result set in Stored Proc output?

Output Expected -

> {"Pulse Data": [{"A":"cc", "B":"ZZ"},{"A":"dd", "B":"YY"},     {"A":"ee", "B":"XX"}]}

Comment: Have you tried removing the 'For Json' and just have the data returned?  It will be json in the Logic App.  Something like 
"ResultSets": {
    "Table1": [
      {
        "invoiceGUID": "f6d62a85-0d70-6739-1564-314b55fd49a5",
        "invoiceNumber": "40001299"
.........

and return ResultsSets.[Table1]

Comment: Yes, thanks. Currently I'm using the same, removed 'For Json'. just using a select statement. Got the same results -->
{"Table1": [{"A":"cc", "B":"ZZ"},{"A":"dd", "B":"YY"}, {"A":"ee", "B":"XX"}]}

Just the "Pulse Data" part is remaining. for which Table1 is coming.

Comment: You could replace Table1 with PulseData in the json string.  Or use a compose something like {"PulseData":  <insert the ResultsSets.[Table1] here using Dynamic Content selection in GUI> } to build the desired result dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

***I had reproduced the same in my local environment and got succeeded.***

[image]

***By doing this below approach in `Azure Logic Apps`, and achieved the required result:***

[image]

***Here is the excepted result:***
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Raj. I'm creating dynamic output which is not stored in a table, using a temp table to store it in Stored Proc, and returning the result set from it.  I'm left with the JSON Root problem only if this can be achieved using this by storing it in a table and then retreiving via Execute a SQL, will test but will it not be an overhead here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday. I was able to resolve this by wrapping the query in to an output variable in the stored procedure, then using the output parameters in the logic app.

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[Something_to_JSON] @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT

SELECT @JSON = ( SELECT DISTINCT something, something
```

[image: Logic App HTTP]

Comment: This is also using FOR JSON AUTO in an Azure SQL DB.

Comment: Not able to wrap the query in the output variable. 
Got Error --> **Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS**